# Symfony doctrine column skip for generating migration

Tags: symfony

I want to stop generating migration for specific entity field, what is possible to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't skip generating migrations for a certin column or entities. The only way to make that is to edit the generated migration file manually.